# Software that directly backs up to Google Drive without caching？

Tags: macos, backup, mojave, google-apps

I have a hard drive that is almost out of free space. I need to back up to Google Drive on Mojave.

First of all, I tried Google Drive file system but it needs cache and I can't copy all my files, because there is not enough cache space. Then I tried `Mountain Duck`, `Expandrive`, and `Cloudmounter`, but they have the same requirements as the Google Drive file system.**(
Google Drive will mount as a local disk and you need to copy files from your hard drive to Google Drive , after the copy finished it will start uploading . If the cache partition only have 70GB,you will not be able to copy a folder larger than 70GB)**

[Google`s Backup ＆ Sync doesn't support the NTFS file system on macOS](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/b-X9s4b1Kew).

I need to find software that directly backs up to Google Drive without copy and caching, where I can pause & continue, and show upload progress.

Comment: Do you want to backup (aka create a remote *copy* of local data) or do you want to *move* data (therefore deleting it locally) to Google Drive?

Comment: @nohillside I think it’s no different.When back up finished ,i can choose to delete or keep the local data.

Comment: It matters as syncing solutions will not help you if you delete local data later.

Comment: what is the actual status of your SSD as reported by Disk Utility

Comment: @Buscar웃 total 256GB  free 80GB,and i want to back up a 2T hard drive.

Comment: @nohillside I already have a lot of files on my google drive.sync may not be suitable.

Comment: @nohillside  Maybe most people have never used these software, I explained the cache problem.

Comment: https://cyberduck.io/ might be an option then. But your question is a bit confusing right now, what's the issue with this link regarding NTFS? Somehow it seems we are missing some parts of the puzzle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/). It supports "access your Google Drive without syncing to your computer".

Comment: I got it , `Cyberduck`  `Transmit 5`  and `ForkLift 3` It is exactly what I want.